# Apache Flink - Gelly - Create a dataset from a list of edges

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have a list of vertices and edges created this way:

```
  val v1 = new Vertex(1L, "foo")
  val v2 = new Vertex(2L, "bar")
  val e1 = new Edge(v1, v2, 0.5)`
```

and want to create a Flink graph using the Graph.fromDataSet method (or any other for this matter). How can I transform those edges and vertices in something that is readable for Flink?

Thank you!!

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/libs/gelly_guide.html#graph-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of vertices `val vertices: Seq[Vertex[Long, String]] = ...` and edges `val edges: Seq[Edge[Long, String]] = ...` you can create a `Graph` using the `Graph.fromCollection` method:

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val vertices = Seq(new Vertex[Long, String](1L, "foo"), new Vertex[Long, String](2L, "bar"))
val edges = Seq(new Edge[Long, String](1L, 2L, "foobar"))

val graph = Graph.fromCollection(vertices, edges, env)
```

It is noteworthy that you have to import the Scala version of `org.apache.flink.graph.scala.Graph`.

Alternatively, you can also first create an `edgeDataset: DataSet[Edge[Long, String]]` and a `vertexDataSet: DataSet[Vertex[Long, String]]` using the `ExecutionEnvironment`. A `Graph` can then be created calling the `Graph.fromDataSet` method:

```
val vertexDataset = env.fromCollection(vertices)
val edgeDataset = env.fromCollection(edges)

val graph = Graph.fromDataSet(vertexDataset, edgeDataset, env)
```